# Amazon s3 storage for social networking-like content management

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have requirements similar to any social networking platform. The exact details are:

1. User can post content in groups
2. All users in a group can view that content
3. Users can upload/download content
4. Not a fixed amount of users/groups. i.e. its a public service, so I can't explicitly administer access lists.

I have taken a look at [this](http://darkvaderdin.tumblr.com/post/29293674994/secure-multi-user-file-storage-with-amazon). The summary is as follows:

#### DOWNLOADS

1. User requests images he wants to see
2. We generate temporary time-limited URLs to the user. Amazon S3 API
   allows you to generate temporary URLs for any private object you
   have stored in S3.You can set an expiry time for this URL and
   hand it down to the user.Generally, this is how S3 images are shown
   in websites. We use that mechanism to pass down the URLs through our
   API.   After a set time, you no longer have access.

#### UPLOADS

It was trickier with uploads…

1. We first made the decision users can only post to
   [ourS3bucketPath]/[userId]/*imagename.jpg* path. With S3, you can
   have restricted access to a specific key path for a user.
2. When the user wants to post, he asks the server for temporary access.               Amazon provides an interesting temporary user called a “federated user”.
   You can create one on the fly and they die out just like the
   temporary URLs after a set time. Furthermore, you can limit access
   to specifically just a S3 bucket key-path. So here, we provision a
   new federated user for a short time.
3. The user tells the server about
   images that are going to be uploaded.
4. The user uploads to amazon to
   given bucket path.
5. User confirms with the server of the completed
   download. Done.

The download aspect of this is fine, but I am not so sure about the upload. 
After making a federated user, if user uploads a file to s3 , and then tells my server a pathname, it is possible to manually change the path name for malicious intents.

How do I do the following :

- Allow an authorised user (which my own server will determine) to view files.
- Allow an authorised user(again,my server will determine) to upload files.

I would also welcome suggestions for bucket structure naming. 
I have thought of :

CONTENT(bucket name) -> ->uuid named file

This means, if there are a million groups , there will be a million group folders, followed by some uuid which would represent the file itself.

My server will record the uuids, and calculate the absolute path by using group id, which will also be saved in my own server.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a temporary user seems like overkill, particularly when there's a more straightforward approach available:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-authentication-HTTPPOST.html

Uploading a file with a form post allows you to create and sign a *policy document* that can't be tampered with, and this policy document can constrain not only the key (path) for the upload, but also can optionally limit the size of uploaded files -- S3 will reject a file that's too large.  (Or small).

---

Also a point of possible clarification:

> Amazon S3 API allows you to generate temporary URLs for any private object you have stored in S3.

That depends on what you mean by "API."  It's not S3 that generates these -- that's done entirely in local code, without contacting S3.  The SDKs have code that does this for you, or you can write your own using published specs.  I have even written a MySQL stored function that can generate these directly from the database, in a query, given the URL as an argument.

Depending on your application, it might also be of interest to you to look info how CloudFront can support pre-signed URLs for bucket content (where CloudFront is in front of the bucket) -- a CloudFront pre-signed URL, using a "custom policy" can do a couple of things an S3 pre-signed URL can't -- restrict use of the URL by IP address, and allow access to all the objects matching a certain path pattern -- like `https://example.com/files/uuid/images/*`.

> You can use the wildcard character that matches zero or more characters (*) or the wild-card character that matches exactly one character (?) anywhere in the string.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-creating-signed-url-custom-policy.html#private-content-custom-policy-statement-examples

You could conceivably save some processing time for your application server by signing this once and then string-replacing the path for each object that will be visible, using a base signed URL. This only works when CloudFront is handling the authentication -- S3 signed URLs for download don't support wildcards.

Signing URLs is pretty fast, but it does involve some fairly heavy bit-twizzling behind the scenes, so if a lot of images will be visible from the same html page, those milliseconds can start to add up, and this could be a useful optimization... not to mention that you should typically see faster downloads with CloudFront since frequently-accessed objects are cached nearer to the user downloading them.

Answer (score 2):

If you site/application never gets that busy, then almost any naming convention will work - so the structure you mentioned would work, but generally for performance reason, you would be better of not having lots of objects that all start with the same prefix - you want to randomize the beginning part of the object name, not the end part of the folder name, so if you hope to grow and have a very busy site down the road, you might want to plan for that now:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html

> Amazon S3 maintains an index of object key names in each AWS region.
>   Object keys are stored in UTF-8 binary ordering across multiple
>   partitions in the index. The key name dictates which partition the key
>   is stored in. Using a sequential prefix, such as timestamp or an
>   alphabetical sequence, increases the likelihood that Amazon S3 will
>   target a specific partition for a large number of your keys,
>   overwhelming the I/O capacity of the partition. ***If you introduce some
>   randomness in your key name prefixes, the key names, and therefore the
>   I/O load, will be distributed across more than one partition.***

**However:**

> The Amazon S3 best practice guidelines in this topic apply only if you
>   are routinely processing 100 or more requests per second. If your
>   typical workload involves only occasional bursts of 100 requests per
>   second and less than 800 requests per second, you don't need to follow
>   these guidelines.